# What is all this ForeUI spam?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Recently a lot of different new users have gotten Necromancer badges for answering with recommendations to use ForeUI on various old posts. Could they be collaborating to spam the site or is this genuinely the community supporting this product? Examples:

- [smartutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220647/how-do-you-prototype-your-software-ui/2261034#2261034) - member for 4 days
- [Henry Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639820/planning-web-applications/2260882#2260882) - member for today
- [Amanda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535774/iphone-ui-controls-for-winforms/2260938#2260938) - member for today
- [David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401370/form-designer-for-dummies/2260999#2260999) - member for today
- [whitney](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687942/is-there-a-free-website-prototype-designing-tool/2260337#2260337) - member for today

There may be other examples too.

Comment: Great catch. Also add Whitney: http://stackoverflow.com/users/272670/whitney - Each has 6 upvotes on one question, each has 61 rep. Very suspicious!

Comment: Also see the overview of active questions mentioning ForeUI. A lot of recent posts, all by new users: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=foreui&tab=active

Comment: I wonder what else Amanda used her 19 upvotes on...

Comment: Update: those accounts are all deleted now. I wonder if that was the actions of a moderator or someone trying to cover their tracks.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Great catch on this.  All of those accounts were sock puppets.  They posted those answers and upvoted each other to get the top answers you linked to (now deleted).  Thanks a lot for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: It's too bad this person decided to abuse the system.  ForeUI might actually be a good product.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I totally agree.  By spamming the site and abusing puppet accounts they've just made their company look bad to everyone who reads this.

Comment: @Bill: did any of these users leave a contact email in their profile? I wonder if it would be fruitful to either contact the user(s), or contact the company and warn them that someone is making them look bad to the community (possibly themselves, in which case someone deserves to get fired!)

Comment: @Ether: One user was suspended and all of the sock puppets deleted, so an email was definitely sent explaining that much.  The only time moderators will take that kind of drastic action *without* sending an email is if the user doesn't provide one.  You raise a very interesting point about the possibility (however slim) of a 3rd party being responsible for this.  It really looks like someone inside the company was trying to promote the product, but I'm not 100% sure with the information I have available.

Comment: Is this also a sock puppet promoting ForeUI: http://stackoverflow.com/users/201700/cody ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm quite sure of it. Smartutor has answered three questions, all about prototyping and he links to ForeUI in all of them.

I guess it's not coincidence that 4 new members mention this software at the same time.

Comment: OK, I have now flagged them all as spam. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't jumping to conclusions! Thanks.

Comment: And all with massive upvotes. I bet they come from each other. Good catch @Mark!

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the day, if the software author keeps spamming the site with advertisement like this, it will only hurt him:

- ForeUI might become part of the blocked content list and his product will never be mentioned by legitimate users.
- His IP range will be blocked and won't be able to use SO for reference.
- ... ?

Comment: Profit! (15 chars)

Comment: Who can see the IP address/IP range?